# Transfering balance between VISA cards in different continents

Tags: credit-card, visa, balance-transfer

Is it possible to transfer credit card balance from a VISA card issued in Europe to a VISA card issued in the US? I've never done balance transfers before, and I (US card holder) need to help my parents (Europe card holder) pay off their CC debt.

Comment: That's up to the two banks behind those cards. Talk to them.

Comment: I know in the US, you cannot use one VISA account to pay another one.

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge, credit card balance cannot be transfered like that.

On the other hand, **debit** card balance can. All banks have an online portal where you can log in and see all of your accounts. (Another options is to call or go to the bank and go through the same process)

To transfer to banks in other countries, you need both their account details (Person's Name, Account Number) and the bank's international identifiers (Exact Name, Swift Number).

If you have that information, you can simply transfer the money and then your parents (or you) can use it to pay the debt.

Another option would be to assign yourself as the Debt payer (if the bank allows it) and other options would be simple money lending services like, for example, Western Union.

Also, be sure that your bank will know ALL the possible ways you could proceed.

Hope this helps!

Robert